# What does this code do? (c++, classes and arrays)

Tags: c++, arrays, class

```
IntArray::IntArray (int *array, int sz)
{
_size = sz;
int  ia = new int[_size];
for (int ix=0; ix<_size; ++ix)
ia[ix] = array[ix];
}
```

Hello, I'm currently studying C++ for beginners by Stanley Lipmann and I'm going through creating of abstract arrays with Classes help. Can someone explain me what does this code do? By my guess it assigns "sz" value (from outside of class) to "_size", then we create the "ia" dynamic array and after all it assigns values from "array" pointer (that outside of class) to an "ia" array. Thanks :D

Comment: Yes, you are correct in your understanding. I would advise against using `int` as a type for array size.

Comment: It just leaks memory

Comment: @t.m., no, provided code does not leak any memory.

Comment: @t.m. Not unless he does `delete[] ia` in his destructor (or use a vector).

Comment: Make a clone of an array?

Comment: The provided code is implementing a constructor of a class called `IntArray`

Comment: Oh I thought ia is defined in that scope

Comment: @SergeyA: Assuming that somewhere there is an `IntArray::~IntArray() { delete ia; }`.

Comment: @FishTheBig That's a terrible question leaving a lot of speculations what's done in the invisible parts of the complete code. Down and close voted.

Answer (score 0):

That cannot be the full code, where is `_size` defined? Is it a class member? The leading underscore suggests that. I presume that `ia` is also a class member of type `int *`.

What it does is to copy the value of `sz` into the (presumably) member variable `_size`. Then it allocates a new array of `int`. The `for` loop then copies the elements from the given array into the new memory allocated. Looking at the name it will tell you that this is a constructor. It constructs a new array of `int`s by copying the given array.

And by the way, indent your code such that it is easier to read, that will make understanding it easier!

```
IntArray::IntArray(int *array, int sz) {
    _size = sz;
    ia = new int[_size];
    for (int ix = 0; ix < _size; ++ix)
        ia[ix] = array[ix];
}
```

You can use the amazing `clang-format` for all your formatting needs.

You can throw in a `const` to the `array` and `sz` parameters, that way you can also create new `IntArray` instances from constant arrays.

Comment: Yeah, I know that code shown by me is not full, but i got the answer i needed. Thanks!)

Comment: @FishTheBig You should consider that StackOverflow isn't made to get the answers you personally need, but provide concise answers (for concise questions!) that help for ***any future research*** here. I don't see that value so far, sorry.